# Ruby on Railsの起動で​secret_key_baseの設定が上手く行かず悩んでいます

Tags: ruby-on-rails

現在、Windows上でRuby on Railsを起動しようとしているのですが、以下の様なエラーが出てしまいました。どなたか同じエラーに遭遇した方で対処方法をご存知の方はお教え頂けないでしょうか？

実行した環境は以下のとおりです。

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Ruby:ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800)
Rails:Rails 5.0.7

```
Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:513:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:693:in `build_request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:521:in `build_request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

ちなみに、以下の事はトライしましたが上手く行きませんでした。

・config/secrets.ymlのproductionの部分の"secret_key_base"に、"bundle exec rake secret"で表示された英数字の列を記載して再実行。

追記:
'rail s -e production'実行後にページリロードした後のproduction.logの内容：

```
I, [2018-07-14T07:37:40.076104 #11580]  INFO -- : [77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-14 07:37:40 +0900
F, [2018-07-14T07:37:40.078138 #11580] FATAL -- : [77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b]   
F, [2018-07-14T07:37:40.078138 #11580] FATAL -- : [77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
F, [2018-07-14T07:37:40.078138 #11580] FATAL -- : [77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b]   
F, [2018-07-14T07:37:40.079125 #11580] FATAL -- : [77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
[77252a09-038f-4973-8812-a486d9664c2b] puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

・'rails routes'の実行結果

```
You don't have any routes defined!

Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.

For more information about routes, see the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.
```

Comment: `secrets.yml`をリポジトリに登録しておらず、`secret_key_base`の更新が反映されていないということはないでしょうか?

Comment: config/secrets.ymlを元に戻して`SECRET_KEY_BASE=\`rake secret\` rails s -e production`ってやったらどうなります？今の設定でlocalでproduction起動できますか？

Comment: @tanalab2  コメントありがとうございます。ローカルの環境でやっており、ファイルを開き直したら更新されていたので、反映されていないという事はないと思います。

Comment: @豚吐露 アドバイスありがとうございます。ご説明して頂いた方法を試してみたところ、以下の様なメッセージが表示されてしまいました。

=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.7 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.11.4 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: local環境でproduction動かしたいんですね。そのメッセージが表示された後、ブラウザなどでアクセスしたらどうなりますか？同じerror内容がlog出力されますか？

Comment: @豚吐露  まずはローカルで動作検証してみようという段階でした。アクセスし直した後のproduction.logの更新内容を見たら、メインの投稿に追記した様なメッセージが表示されていました。

Comment: @nobelnambu `No route matches [GET] "/"`は`/`に対応するルートがないというエラーだと思います。ターミナルから `rails routes`を実行したときに、`URI Pattern`の`/`に対応する`Controller#Action`は表示されますか? もし表示されないのであれば、表示されている他の`URI Pattern`でブラウザを表示してください。

Comment: @tanalab2 'rails routes'の結果を追記しました。参考にしている書籍では特にroutes設定はいらないのかと思っていましたが、ここが正しく設定されていないようです。config/routes.rbの設定方法を調べてみます。

Comment: う～ん、何かproduction云々じゃ無く、環境が壊れてるような。。。productionじゃなかったら閲覧はできます？development環境`rails s -b 0.0.0.0`で起動して閲覧したことはありますか？

Comment: @豚吐露 development環境でもやはり駄目でした...。ご指摘されている通り、環境構築に失敗した様な気がするので、一度アンインストールしてから再度環境を構築してみます。

Comment: とりあえず、適当な場所に`rails new hoge`とかで作って、`cd hoge`して、`bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0`で動くか？からですね。それで動いたのに、後で動かなくなったら、自分のせいって分かります。https://railstutorial.jp/chapters/beginning?version=5.1#cha-beginning ココらへんが分かりやすいと思いますんで、参考にしてみてください。

Comment: @豚吐露 環境を構築し直して再度挑戦してみました。結果としては、ルーティングが適切に出来ていなかった事が原因だと分かりました。コントローラーにメソッドを追加してrender plain:"text"を記入する事で、textが表示されていたので、先に進んでみようと思います。手元の書籍ではすぐにアクセスしてページが表示される旨の説明がされていたので戸惑ってしまっていました。